# In what order will facts found in files under a module/lib/facter/* be loaded on a puppet client?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, facter

I have the following file structure:

```
lib
└── facter
    ├── rackspace.rb
    ├── system_load.rb
    └── users.rb
```

I want to use a custom fact value found in `system_load.rb` (let's call this `:system_me` fact) in another custom fact that I am writing and defined in `users.rb`. Like this:

```
# users.rb

Facter.add('sogood') do
  you = ''
  me = Facter.value(:system_me)
  if me == 'foo'
    you = 'bar'
  end
  setcode do
    you
  end
end
```

However, I am worried on what happens if `system_me` fact value doesn't exist yet before client tries to run `sogood`.

**So my question is:**

1. Are fact files like the one seen in the lib folder structure above loaded in alphabetical order of the filename (`rackspace.rb -> system_load.rb -> users.rb`)  when I run `puppet apply —facterpath=module/lib/facter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a fact resolution attempts to obtain the `Facter.value()` for another fact that has not yet been loaded then Facter will immediately attempt to load the needed fact. That means that

- No, fact files are not necessarily loaded in alphabetical order, but
- you nevertheless should not need to worry about fact loading order.

You do need to avoid creating dependency loops among facts, but custom facts relying on built-in facts will never cause such a loop.